# Chrome is not Opening in Catalina

Tags: macos, catalina, install, google-chrome, mac-mini

I have upgraded Mojave to Catalina. The Previous chrome browser has not opened a single time after Catalina installation. I have tried lots of ways but none worked.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Can you list what methods have you tried? Are you unable to launch the app? Did you see the app icon in the Dock? Have you tried reinstalling the app?

Comment: i have tried uninstalling and installing latest, tried opening from dock and launcher too, tried to install older stable version, tried to restart mac on every installation, tried giving all the permission explicitly, tried deleting all the previous folder that is creating during chrome installation, tried all the above step using terminal......Nothing worked :-(

Comment: Tried same above steps to install Chromium too, on that i also had a bad luck :-( PS- I am using Catalina since a month

Comment: Try it in a freshly created new user account.

Comment: i have 2 accounts admin and guest, failed in both